# How would I convert the data type int[] to the data type int

Tags: arrays, types, converters, type-mismatch

I have set up an array to randomize 5 different numbers in one class. In a different class I have prompted a user to guess the random number, and must reference the number each time to determine whether they have guessed correctly or not. My issue is that the numbers being randomized are in the data type int[], and I need to compare them to the data type int. When trying to reference the randomized numbers I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int". Any advice on how I would do that?

Class diceNumGen

```
        final static int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
      public static int[] randNumArray = new int [ARRAY_SIZE];
      
      public static int[] randNums(){
            
                  for(int i=0; i < randNumArray.length; i++) {
                        randNumArray[i] = (int) (Math.random()*12);
                        
                        System.out.println(randNumArray);
                        
            }
            return randNumArray.clone();
            
      }}
```

Class Bet

```
static Bet bet = new Bet();
      diceNumGen newClassObj = new diceNumGen();
      int secondArray = diceNumGen.randNumArray;
      //Set Turns variable where turns = 5
      
      public int turnsToGo = 5;
      
      //Set up the bet() method
      public void bet() {
            
            //Sets up the options as an array to be on the JOptionPane, each are numbered 0, 1, and 2 respectively
            String[] options = {"Guess below 7", "Guess 7", "Guess above 7"};
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome here, I'm newcomer too, this is my first answer.
I assume that you are using java, because of keywords, it is good to define the programming language in the question or tags to get better responses.

the first thing about your code is you don't need a whole class for generating an array, an ordinary function like this would be OK too:

```java
    static int[] randomGen(int len){
        java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        int[] randoms = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            randoms[i] = rand.nextInt(12);
        }
        return randoms;
    }
```

the next thing is, please indent your code, un-indented code (or badly indented code) will confuse the reader.

and about your question, at the first point why are you creating random array with the size of 5? if you just need one random number, just create one random number (with your `Math.random()` or better, `nextInt(12)` in Random class)

if user have 5 chances to guess same number you don't need 5 random numbers. just use this:

```java
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 12);
```

or if you want user to guess 5 separate numbers, you need a for loop to iterate this random array per user guess.

Good luck in learning java.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Yeah I am trying to create 5 separate random numbers. I do have the for loops you described. The only issue I'm having is that once the numbers have been randomised as part of an array, I need to reference them as "int" rather than "int[]"

Comment: you have 5 different numbers, you should save all of them and iterate them, then why would you save it as int? just change int type and save it as int[], you cannot iterate int of course. something like `int[] secondArray = diceNumGen.randNumArray;`